# Torque applies to one wheel, but inconsistently to the other wheel

Tags: unity, c#, rigidbody

I have a `GameScript` class which is derived by another class `WheelScript`; it is meant to apply torque to a rigidbody in different directions depending upon the key pressed.

However the result to this is that one of the rigidbodies rotates fine but the other one doesn't (say the right wheel rotates but the left doesn't turn or even if it does, it doesn't move with the same angular velocity as the first one)

Base class:

```
public class GameScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameScript instance;
    protected float Force;

    protected virtual void  Print(GameObject gameObject) {
        print(gameObject.name);
    }    

    protected virtual void MoveForward(Rigidbody rigidBody, int identifier) {
        if(identifier == 1)
        {
            rigidBody.AddRelativeTorque(-Vector3.forward * Force); 
        }
        else
        {
            rigidBody.AddRelativeForce(-Vector3.forward * Force);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void MoveLeft(Rigidbody rigidBody, int identifier) {
        if (identifier == 1)
        {
            rigidBody.AddRelativeTorque(-Vector3.forward * Force);
        }
        else
        {
            rigidBody.AddRelativeForce(-Vector3.forward * Force);
        }    
    }

    protected virtual void MoveRight(Rigidbody rigidBody, int identifier) {
        if (identifier == 1)
        {
            rigidBody.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.forward * Force);
        }
        else
        {
            rigidBody.AddRelativeForce(-Vector3.forward * Force);
        }    
    }

    protected virtual void MoveBack(Rigidbody rigidBody, int identifier) {
        if (identifier == 1)
        {
            rigidBody.AddRelativeTorque(-Vector3.forward * Force);
        }
        else
        {
            rigidBody.AddRelativeForce(-Vector3.forward * Force);
        }
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class WheelScript : GameScript
{ 
    [SerializeField] private int identifier;
    Rigidbody body;
    [SerializeField] float force;

    private void Start()
    {
         body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
         Force = force;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            MoveForward(body, identifier);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            MoveLeft(body, identifier);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            MoveRight(body, identifier);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            MoveBack(body, identifier);
        }
    }
}
```

and similarly for the other wheel with only difference being that of axis as its axis is (0,0,-1)

Hinge Joint for left wheel is visible in this picture
[image: Hinge Joint for left wheel is visible in this picture]

Hinge Joint for right wheel is visible here in this picture

[image: Hinge Joint for right wheel is visible here in this picture]

This is how each wheel is aligned

[image: This is how each wheel is aligned]

Hinges are attached to the pivot in the opposite direction as marked in the circle

[image: Hinges are attached to the pivot in opposite direction]

**Also I think I forgot to mention but the WheelScript is attached to both the wheels (it is the script component for both wheels)**

Comment: Can you show us how you've configured your left and right wheels in the Unity inspector?

Comment: Hi I have updated the post with the pictures

Comment: I have also added the image of the character for more clarity , the wheels are supposed to move when torque is applies ,The model works with individual scripts for both wheels but not with the code that I have posted

Comment: It looks like you've shared the same inspector twice, and did not show us how you've configured your WheelScript, only the HingeJoint. Try to put yourself in the position of a reader who is trying to reproduce your exact situation, starting from a new, empty project, using only the information in this post.

Comment: Hey, I am sorry , re - edited the question with screens please check

Comment: Is there any configuration different between the left and right wheel? (Note that if we could see both wheels in your screenshots, I would not have to ask) Also, have you considered using [WheelColliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-WheelCollider.html) for this purpose?

Comment: No there is nothing different ...even the axis are the same , I am pretty new to unity and had experimented with wheel colliders but to no avail ... Wheels are exact copies of each other ,the only difference is the anchor at which they are hinged

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code though ,does it have something to do with Mono behaviour ?,Why is the torque disproportionate ....